# Как просканировать массив и выполнить заданное условие?

Tags: php, массивы

Внутри переменной `$categories` содержится прикрепленный ниже массив.
Как задать условие, чтобы PHP просканировал массив и выполнил команду `echo $categories -> category_name`, только если внутри него имеется `$child->category_name;`, значение которого равняется, например, "Ноутбуки"?

```html
<pre>
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 3Q
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_name] => Ноутбуки
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_name] => Планшеты
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 4Good
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_name] => Ноутбуки
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_name] => Планшеты
                        )

                )

        )
</pre>
```

Comment: $row=count($arr);for ($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
    print_r($arr[$i]['childs'][0]);
}

Comment: @Bloom выводится в ответ ошибка `0 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: а если просто  print_r($arr[$i]['childs']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Для начала начнем обходить массив ОБЪЕКТОВ
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    // Теперь обойдем массив ОБЪЕКТОВ из свойства childs и проверим что там есть
    foreach ($category->childs as $child) {
        if ($child->category_name === 'Ноутбуки') {
            // выводим название родительской категории
            echo $category->category_name;
            // Так как нужное название найдено 
            // проверять следующие элементы не имеет смысла
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: Подскажите, получается, это цикл внутри цикла?

Comment: Да, это цикл внутри цикла.